# How to get button to stay on right top screen fixed and still mobile responsive with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, fixed

I Made a custom button and wish to use it as navbar toggle, and make the button stay on the right top of the screen on all time and being mobile responsive, all solution i found make the button position:fixed. but this is not mobile responsive, i tried pull-right class but it only works when i am on the top of the screen and not fixed. as long i apply the position fixed it goes to the left side of the screen, use left or right won't work if i want it mobile responsive. anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others said:

```
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

..should work fine. Also it's a good idea to link a fiddle. If you want it to keep it mobile resposive, just include it in the bootstrap grid.

Made this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7wz81yu/)

Answer (score 0):

try to apply below css

```
.customButton{
    top : 0;
    right : 0;
    position: fixed;
 }
```

Comment: it just went towards left of my screen

Answer (score 0):

Just Try and fail and solved it.
Simply wrap it with div element or other element, and apply the div float right and some little padding i got my button set.

```
<div style='float:right;'>
   <button style='position:fixed;'></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
<input type="button" style="position:fixed; top:0px; right:0px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For navbars Bootstraps provides special classes if you want the navbar to be fixed. Use ".navbar-fixed-top" from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-fixed-top

The floating can be done with the ".pull-right" as you said, or with ".navbar-left". Also you need to pay attention to what you put in ".collapsed" area.

Sometimes you might need to duplicate some links for both mobile and desktop views. You can also use the responsive classes, like ".hidden-xs", etc. see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities